# How to correctly read an endless stream from InternetRadio using Indy TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, wget, indy, internet-radio, idhttp

I am writing a UPNP-Controller.

To supply the Artist and Title, it's necessary that I can get the metadata, probably supplied as XML somewhere in the Stream.

For that, I want to read the (endless) stream from InternetRadio and detect the XML. I am not sure what it contains exactly, but I struggle with receiving the Stream as `TMemoryStream`. The program gets stuck after the `Get` command.

```
procedure TformMain.GetUrlStream(url: string; var m: Tmemorystream); 
var
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  XMLStr: string;
  IO : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IO := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IO.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    IdHttp1.IOHandler := IO;
    IdHttp1.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
    IdHttp1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36';
    IdHttp1.Request.Connection := 'close'; // Close connection after each request

    IdHTTP1.Get(url,m);           // --> here the program stops

  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TIdHTTP.Get()` does not exit until the response ends (or when an error occurs). But if the response is endless, you get stuck waiting for completion that never happens. What does the raw response actually look like? If the server sends a `chunked` response, for instance, you can either 1) handle the chunks in the `TIdHTTP.OnChunkReceived` event, or 2) enable the `hoNoReadChunked` flag in the `TIdHTTP.Options` property and then read the data directly from the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` after `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits. It is hard to say what will work for you without seeing the actual response.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi Remy, I read a similar answer of you in a other post but did not get a clue how to implement it. - Because im really bad in object oriented programming. How can i implement a Http.onChunkReceived in this procedure? Have you a code-snipped I can relay on?
At the moment I get no response at all.

Comment: Since you are creating everything dynamically at runtime (instead of at design-time), you would have to declare and assign an event handler manually as well. As that is not in your skillset yet, let's make sure that is even necessary. You can capture the raw HTTP headers/response data in real-time by assigning a `TIdLog...` component such as  `TIdLogFile` to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property. What does it actually capture? What the response headers actually look like will dictate how the response should be handled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy for your sugestions. Here a short update: I implemented ´TIdHTTP´ the way you pointed me. 1 out of 4 ´URL´s did send a chunked. The small stream I could monitor did not contain anything readable. So I search for an other approach and probably go to the bookshop to find doumentation about standards in transmitting internetradio. Perhaps even a solution in Phyton as I remeber having read.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
Hi Remy
I come back, because wget does not support SSL and I am not equiped to recompile it.
I succeeded in getting the stream in the logfile as you sugested and can abort the IdHTTP.GET by freeing the stream after 100 

chunks. But I do not find the needed textportion: `StreamTitle=`.

When I get the stream with wget and press ctrl+C I get the file: reply.txt witch contains what I need. 
`wget --header="Icy-MetaData:1" -S -O reply.txt http://onair.krone.at/kronehit.mp3`

Have you an explanation why IdHTTP.GEt is filtering this or what paramter is to adjust?

Comment: `TIdHTTP` doesn't filter anything. Whatever you can do with `wget`, you should be able to do with `TIdHTTP` as well, eg: `IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Icy-MetaData'] := '1'; IdHTTP.Get('http://onair.krone.at/kronehit.mp3', ...);` But since this MP3 plays endlessly, `TIdHTTP.Get()` won't exit. So, you need to analyze the data WHILE the MP3 is downloading, and to help you with that, I need to see the actual HTTP headers that the server is sending back to you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
bingo...  `IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Icy-MetaData'] := '1';`  did the trick. - Thanks!!!
Gladly I send you one of the headers in the next comment. But I have thousends, because of the number of InternetRadios availabe. --- Meanwhile i succseeded in grabbing the data i want by writing a EXE that writes the content of the logfile. (I just make the `IdHTTP.GET` and after 3 seconds i free the memoystream and have the data in the logfile.) -- Sofar it works, but killing the separate EXE makes more trouble as I thaught. Perhaps I should not use a Form.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 200 OK<EOL>Content-Type: audio/aacp<EOL>Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2024 22:33:29 GMT<EOL>icy-br:64<EOL>ice-audio-info: samplerate=48000;channels=2;bitrate=64<EOL>icy-br:64<EOL>icy-pub:1<EOL>Server: IcecastSC 1.2.5<EOL>Set-Cookie: IcecastId=1711233209-1419444266; Max-Age=7776000; Domain=infomaniak.ch<EOL>Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store<EOL>Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT<EOL>Connection: Close<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Icy-MetaData<EOL>

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, SOURCE, PUT, HEAD, STATS<EOL>icy-metaint:16000<EOL><EOL>

Comment: Is all the metadata you are interested in located only in the HTTP headers? If so, then have you tried using `TIdHTTP.Head()` instead of `TIdHTTP.Get()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau
No! Its at Position 1024 or later in the stream.  --- But gladly I managed that all works without interfierence. Maybe not in the state of the art :-) -- So for me it is OK!!!!!
I thank you - you helped me a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a completly different way to get hold on the `Metadata` of the radiostream with the help of `wget.exe`.
Here an exerpt of the code:

```
function TformMain.GetMetaTitle(url: string) : string;
var
  cmd: string;
  search,search2: string;
  p,p2 : integer;
  res : string;
  str :string;

begin
    //Get ici-MetaData
    result := '';
    StringReplace(url,'https://','http://',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

    cmd := 'wget --header="Icy-MetaData:1" -S -O reply.txt '+url;
    Memodummy.Clear;
    GetDosOutput(cmd,'',Memodummy,15); //15 erwartete metatags + 1 stream
    if processExists('wget.exe') then begin
        WinExec('taskkill /IM wget.exe /F', SW_HIDE);
    end;
    sleep(1000);  //Wait for Taskkill

    //Locate begin of title
    search := 'icy-metaint:';
    search2 := char(13);
    p := pos(search,Memodummy.Text,1);
    p2 := pos(search2,Memodummy.Text,p);
    res := Trim(copy(Memodummy.Text,p+length(search)+1,p2 - p - (length(search)+1)));

    //extract title if possible
    try
      str := TFile.ReadAllText('reply.txt');
      search := 'StreamTitle=';
      search2 := ';';
      p := pos(search,str,strtoint(res));
      p2 := pos(search2,str,p);
      result := Trim(copy(str,p+length(search)+1,p2 - p - (length(search)+1)-1));
      result := THTMLEncoding.HTML.Encode(result);
    except
      on e:exception do begin
        memo1.lines.Append('Fehler in GetMetatitle: ' +e.Message);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

The part of `Locate begin of title` could even be skipped and the outputfile (reply.txt) directly searched for `StreamTitle=`. So no output of the Dos-Window (here Memodummy) has to be analyzed.
But so the structure is more clear I think.

**So the short version would be:** (untested)

```
function TformMain.GetMetaTitle(url: string) : string;
var
    cmd: string;
    search,search2: string;
    p,p2 : integer;
    str :string;
    begin
        //Get ici-MetaData
        result := '';
        StringReplace(url,'https://','http://',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    
        cmd := 'wget --header="Icy-MetaData:1" -S -O reply.txt '+url;
        Shellexecute(cmd,........);
        if processExists('wget.exe') then begin
            WinExec('taskkill /IM wget.exe /F', SW_HIDE);
        end;
        sleep(1000);  //Wait for Taskkill
    
        //extract title if possible
        try
          str := TFile.ReadAllText('reply.txt');
          search := 'StreamTitle=';
          search2 := ';';
          p := pos(search,str,strtoint(res));
          p2 := pos(search2,str,p);
          result := Trim(copy(str,p+length(search)+1,p2 - p - (length(search)+1)-1));
          result := THTMLEncoding.HTML.Encode(result);
        except
          on e:exception do begin
            memo1.lines.Append('Fehler in GetMetatitle: ' +e.Message);
          end;
        end;
    end;
```